# How do I convert the "name" and "content" attributes of specific meta tags into a JavaScript object literal?

Tags: javascript, object, type-conversion, meta

I have several meta tags that look like this:

```
<meta name="Addan:id" content="2098949824982" />
<meta name="Addan:name" content="Addan Salahehin" />
```

How do I convert these `meta` tags (there is more than 1) into a JavaScript object that looks this:

```
{ "id" : "2098949824982" , "name" : "Addan Salahehin" }
```

I've tried to use the `forEach` method but `Addan` isn't getting removed.

I'd like to use Vanilla JS and not jQuery.

Comment: "*I've tried to use the forEach method*" - please post the code you've used even when it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be getting this error because you are not removing or checking for the *"Addan:"* part of your meta's name, try using this instead:

```js
let metas = {};
[...document.querySelectorAll("meta")].forEach(meta => {
  const split = meta.name.split(":");
  if (split[0].trim().toLowerCase() == "addan") {
    metas[split[1]] = meta.content;
  }
});
console.log(metas);
```

```html
<meta name="Addan:id" content="2098949824982" />
<meta name="Addan:name" content="Addan Salahehin" />
```

When you run the snippet, you should get this output:

```
Object { id: "2098949824982", name: "Addan Salahehin" }
```

**NOTE:** Here is a working [code pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZZqjdM).

Comment: I made you a snippet

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks! I didn't know how to do that :)

Comment: I find this more elegant: `document.querySelectorAll("meta[name^=Addan]").forEach(meta =>   
    metas[meta.name.split(":")[1]] = meta.content
);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the name^=Addan to select the specific metas and create an array or an object

```js
// Array: 
let metas = [...document.querySelectorAll("meta[name^=Addan]")].map(meta => {  
    return {[meta.name.split(":")[1]] : meta.content} 
});
console.log(metas);

// Object

metas = {};
document.querySelectorAll("meta[name^=Addan]").forEach(meta =>   
    metas[meta.name.split(":")[1]] = meta.content
);
console.log(metas);
```

```html
<meta name="Addan:id" content="2098949824982" />
<meta name="Addan:name" content="Addan Salahehin" />
```